# Make HighCharts Axis Labels being and end at my min/max

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Why wont my HighCharts y axis labels begin at 0.5 and end at 17? I have explicitly specified this in the initialisation code but its not adhering to it. Instead the y axis labels begin at 0 and end at 18.

Is there anyway I can control this and force the y axis labels to begin at my min value and end at my max value (and preferably not need to alter my `tickAmount` value)?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0.5,
        max: 17,
        //tickInterval: 10,
        tickAmount: 4,
    },

    series: [{
        data: [[5, 0.7], [10, 5]]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<p>
I am expecting the y axis labels to begin at 0.5 (my min) and end at 17 (my max). Not begin at 0 and end at 20.
</p>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [yAxis.tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner) this will work

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {

  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0.5,
    max: 17,
    tickPositions: [0.5, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 17],

  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [5, 0.7],
      [10, 5]
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<p>
  I am expecting the y axis labels to begin at 0.5 (my min) and end at 17 (my max). Not begin at 0 and end at 20.
</p>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `tickInterval` property with 0.5 value and accommodate the number of visible ticks with `labels.step` property or specify ticks inside `tickPositions` array.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.step
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/bfky8gce/ - setting tickInterval to 0.5
http://jsfiddle.net/1gxp8zt7/ - using tickPositions